# Microsoft API for Serial Communication - C#

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, serial-port, motorola-emdk

I am trying to get two windows mobile devices to communicate with each other.

The API I am using (EMDK) says:

Any Microsoft API can be used for serial communication after the pairing is completed.

So, can anyone point me to an example of serial communications using C# .NET  (Preferably Compact Framework).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446565.aspx)?
Or [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446551.aspx)? (a favorite of mine).
Or maybe an example of it [in use for printing](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/CFPrinterClass.aspx?display=Print)?
Or maybe a [card reader example](http://www.lancelarsen.com/Blog/tabid/72/EntryId/55/SmartDevice-SerialPort-CardSwipe-Code-Example.aspx)?
Or posibly [Bluetooth via VB](http://www.code-magazine.com/articleprint.aspx?quickid=0609051&page=4)?

The web has *loads* of examples.  Generally speaking any example (desktop or device) that uses the [SerialPort class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) will be completely applicable.

Comment: You've appeared to have forgotten that while the .NET CF SerialPort class is okay for simple use it is good at being slightly curious when used in anger (did they fix the curious 1 thread per read pattern in 3.5?). In my experience i've found the OpenNETCF one is more reliable (http://serial.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Nope, not forgotten at all - I still use the OpenNETCF implementation for just about everything I do.

Comment: Thanks for the great info.  I am digging into it...  Thanks also for the link to OpenNetCF serial stuff.